Entropy and local flow of time
I have little training in physics or mathematics beyond HS and early undergrad long ago so apologies for any fundamental misconceptions and/or sloppy use of terms.
As I understand, the flow of time that we perceive is somehow related to or arising from the increasing entropy of the universe.  If this is correct, is there any sense in which the flow of time varies locally when local systems evolve toward equilibrium at different rates?
My garage comes to mind as an example.  After I clean it, it evolves to near thermal equilibrium within a day or two while the rest of my house takes much longer.  If I were to synchronize clocks and place them in my living room and in my garage would they remain synchronized?

They will stay synchronised. The differences are way too small to measure by current technology. Also, we dont really know the full relationship between entropy and time; entropy increase only seems to be related to the direction of time, not its flow, and even there, the relationship is only conjectured. Don't read too much into it.

Be careful to distinguish between time and the flow of time. For more on this see What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?

@naturallyinconsistent.  Thank you. The garage example was tongue in cheek- I should have been more clear about that.   Are there any astronomical phenomenon wherein the system entropy is thought to change dramatically and rapidly such that a local clock would be observed to deviate from a distant observer's clock (or from relativity predicted differences)?   I gather the answer is "no" or that this question is nonsensical but just wanted to clarify.
